# Spring Cloud Stream vs Core Messaging

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

hopefully somebody can explain me the difference between Spring Cloud Stream and Spring Core Messaging.
I couldn't find any comparison regarding advanteges and disadvanteges or differences.

Kind regards

Comment: Spring Cloud Stream is build on top of Spring Integration which uses the Core messaging facilities. The latter is more low-level (using templates etc. to send/receive message) whereas with Spring Cloud Stream you define an interface and everything will be handled for you. What to use dependends on your usecase.

Comment: In my first run I wanted to use RabbitMQ and later maybe Kafka. Is the change of the communication technology wit Core Messaging as simple as with Cloud Stream ?

Comment: No. As it rquires different templates, different listener annotations.

Comment: I‘m completely nee to Java and Spring. Can you please provide a short example for both?